# how to handle pivot swipe gesture through button click event in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8

How to swipe images through button click event just like windows phone Gallery Photo(left to right or vice verse,use 2 button "<" and ">").I have use pivot control to swipe images one by one & list box to collect all images.It is working fine for swipe(touch) gesture.

Comment: <grid><phone:Pivot  x:Name="listbox"ItemsSource="{Binding}"><phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate><DataTemplate><Image  Name="image1"Source="{Binding} />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can easily achieve this via setting the Pivot.SelectedIndex

like

for forward

```
if(Pivot.selectedIndex < Pivot.Items.Count)
    Pivot.selectedIndex++;
else
    Pivot.selectedIndex = 0;
```

for backward

```
if(Pivot.selectedIndex > 0)
    Pivot.selectedIndex--;
else
    Pivot.selectedIndex = Pivot.Items.Count - 1;
```

Comment: can u give simple code for above answer.

Comment: in the button's on click you can add above listed code

Comment: does not show above method. I have shown "Pivot.SelectedIndexProperty" property .I have used xaml pivot control property SelectedIndex="{Binding }"

Comment: This code will be added to click event of buttoons

Comment: I have currently working on.

Comment: Pivot.selectedIndex++ its working fine but Pivot.selectedIndex-- does not work by default it display first image not a last image in listbox

Comment: If i use Pivot.selectedIndex-- then it display first image instead of last image& when i have click button It display 'System.ArgumentException' I have use list box for groupped items  starts from the top to bottom .

Comment: I have use one listbox include pivot control.But currently i have need to display this listbox images swipe  right to left (first image to last image)when i have press button,still it is working fine if i have added "Pivot.selectedIndex++" in button click event,But if  i have need to vice versa i.s i have pickup same list box images and swipe left right(last image to first image ) Pivot.selectedIndex-- not working

Comment: anyone can provide simple code for listbox images display reverse order.in windows phone

Comment: @Siddhu now works check

Comment: Its working fine for swipe images from left to right &vice versa.But some bugs at the time of swiping images(It does not display original image i.s all images at the time of displaying images reflect his right part to left&vice versa ).Same as image displaying in MIRROR.(display MIRROR IMAGE)

Comment: Thanks first of all for your response. I appreciate it.It is working fine & i have  try to implement according to my requirements.I have suggested to you just small modification in xaml file image tag set  FlowDirection="LeftToRight" to avoid display MIRROR IMAGE

Comment: Hay Dude! Its pretty awesome. Thanks +1.
But it throws an exception when go forward and reach to the last index, so I just amend your code a little bit, and Now its working Fine.

if(Pivot.selectedIndex < (Pivot.Items.Count -1))
    Pivot.selectedIndex++;
else
    Pivot.selectedIndex = 0;